# Is Havdalah Mideoraita or Mideraban?

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, havdalah

Is saying "אתה חננתנו"/הבדלה on מוצ''ש is it מן התורה or not?

On one hand I remember hearing it is מן התורה as it part of "זכור" but on the other hand I've heard its only מדרבנן

Please provide sources.

Comment: See [here](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Havdalah#cite_note-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with many questions, we can say that it is a machlokes. The Rambam says that it is from the Torah while Rabbeinu Tam says that it is rabbinic.

[Havdalah in Davening](http://www.bknw.org/uploads/5/9/9/5/5995719/havdalah_in_davening.pdf)

> . Is havdalah a biblical or rabbinic obligation?
>
> 1. Opinion of the Rambam. The Rambam (Hilchot Shabbat 29:1) writes that the biblical commandment of “zachor et yom hashabbat l’kadsho”
>      consists of mentioning the praises of Shabbat when it begins (with
>      kiddush) and when it ends (with havdalah), clearly indicating that the
>      obligation to say havdalah is biblical in nature.
> 2. Opinion of Rabeinu Tam. The Rabeinu Tam is cited in the response of the Rosh (11:3) as having ruled that the obligation to recite havdalah
>      is only rabbinic in nature.

Even according to the Rambam, the particular method used is actually mid'rabbanan

> The source for havdalah b’tfilah. The gemara (Berachot 33a) records
>   that originally the rabbis instituted the recitation of havdalah in
>   davening. Subsequently, when Jews became more affluent and were able
>   to afford wine, the rabbis instead required that it be recited over a
>   cup of wine. In later times, when the financial standing of the Jewish
>   community slipped, the rabbis resorted to the earlier decree to recite
>   havdalah during davening. In order to guarantee that the method with
>   which one is supposed to recite havdalah not change constantly with
>   the affluence of the community, the rabbis made a permanent decree to
>   recite havdalah during davening, and insisted that one who says
>   havdalah in davening still recite havdalah over a cup of wine. (See
>   Rashba ad loc. and Shulchan Aruch Harav 294:2)

Yeshiva Har Etzion has the following

[HALAKHA: A WEEKLY SHIUR IN HALAKHIC TOPICS](http://ccs.infospace.com/ClickHandler.ashx?ld=20150629&app=1&c=pchmeta4&s=pchmeta4&rc=pchmeta4&dc=&euip=71.179.208.30&pvaid=30bd478621174cefa6a5046967f5100c&dt=Desktop&fct.uid=jp05i5bmm0%253D3C0A5232-483E-49C2-&en=y2HsFdiwRo4XG8lJBjnZfEIb5hJQYreFhtNwVgkmv86Fivq2R5BG3f70oZbEEgfdEZn8H%2fCflYk%3d&du=etzion.org.il%2fvbm%2fenglish%2farchive%2fhalak64%2f28havdala.doc&ru=http%3a%2f%2fetzion.org.il%2fvbm%2fenglish%2farchive%2fhalak64%2f28havdala.doc&ap=9&coi=771&cop=main-title&npp=9&p=0&pp=0&pct=http%3a%2f%2fsct.pch.com%2fimages%2f__kl.gif%3fun%3db02f3ac1-a606-4926-9349-6cab7c6338a3%26uid%3divn5pfrgaupda2vffr2lm59f95%26mobility%3ddesktop%26searchID%3divn5pfrgaupda2vffr2lm59f951435609906725&ep=9&mid=9&hash=32C69875900EAB2A91039793C09EBACA)

> Does the obligation of havdala originate from the Torah, or was it
>   instituted by Chazal?  Some Rishonim indicate that havdala constitutes
>   a rabbinic obligation, whereas others imply that it originates from
>   the Torah.  If, indeed, havdala is required according to Torah law,
>   the question arises as to the Biblical source of this obligation.  The
>   Rambam writes in Hilkhot Shabbat (29:1):
>
> "There is a mitzvat asei from the Torah to declare the sanctity of the
>   Shabbat day, as it says, 'Remember the day of Shabbat, to make it
>   holy,' meaning, speak about it in terms of praise and sanctity.  One
>   must speak of it when it enters and when it departs: when it enters –
>   through the kiddush of the day; when it departs – through havdala."
>
> This passage implies that the havdala obligation stems from the mitzva
>   of "zakhor" ("Remember the Shabbat day… " – Shemot 20:8).  The Maggid
>   Mishneh notes that other Rishonim derive the havdala obligation from
>   the verse in Parashat Shemini, "To distinguish between the sacred and
>   the mundane" (Vayikra 10:10).
>
> This issue regarding the Biblical source of the mitzva may yield
>   several important ramifications.  For example, the Minchat Chinukh
>   (mitzva 31) raises the question of why we make no mention of the
>   Exodus in havdala as we do in kiddush.  If the obligation originates
>   from the verse in Parashat Shemini, the answer is easily resolved:
>   since the requirement of havdala stems from a different source from
>   kiddush, we should not expect its laws to parallel those of kiddush. 
>   If, however, we view "zakhor" – the source of the obligation of
>   kiddush – as the source of havdala, as well, then these two should
>   indeed follow the same format.  The Minchat Chinukh leaves this
>   question unresolved.  Rav Tzvi Pesach Frank (Har Tzvi, O.C. 157)
>   suggests that we perhaps fulfill the obligation to mention the Exodus
>   through the recitation of arvit on Motza'ei Shabbat before havdala. 
>   Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (cited in Shemirat Shabbat Ke-hilkhata,
>   chapter 58, note 18) claimed that even if we view havdala as part of
>   the mitzva of zakhor, this would not necessarily require mentioning
>   the Exodus in havdala.  It suffices to mention the Exodus while
>   reciting kiddush, and there is no need to mention it again in havdala.

Comment: Why is the link so convoluted?

Comment: @DoubleAA the pointer that I got was to a word document at Yeshiva har Etzion and I got the link by clicking "copy link address" I do not know how to simplify it. If you can fix it, go ahead and edit it and let me know what you did.